# What's isotopy of framings?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

I am reading R.E.Gompf and A.I. Stipsicz, 4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus.At pp.100-101,the authors say "isotopy classes of framings."I don't know how to determine isotopy to framings.Please tell me about this.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$\varphi_0, \varphi_1: V^k \hookrightarrow M^n$$ be two embeddings of the $k$-manifold $V$ into the $n$-manifold $M$, both with trivial normal bundle. Furthermore, let $f_0$ be a framing of the normal bundle $\nu(\varphi_0: V \hookrightarrow M)$, and similarly let $f_1$ be a framing of the normal bundle $\nu(\varphi_1: V \hookrightarrow M)$. Then $(\varphi_0, f_0)$ and $(\varphi_1, f_1)$ are two framed embeddings of $V$ into $M$.

The usual definition of an **isotopy between the embeddings $\varphi_0$ and $\varphi_1$** is a homotopy $$F: V \times [0,1] \longrightarrow M$$ between $\varphi_0$ and $\varphi_1$ such that $F(-,t)$ is an embedding for all fixed $t$.

Note that by the Tubular Neighborhood Theorem, a normal framing $f$ of an embedding $$\varphi: V^k \hookrightarrow M^n$$ with trivial normal bundle uniquely determines an embedding $$\tilde{\varphi}: V^k \times D^{n-k} \hookrightarrow M^n$$ up to isotopy, where $D^{n-k}$ is the $(n-k)$-dimensional disk. Then we say two framed embeddings $(\varphi_0,f_0)$ and $(\varphi_1,f_1)$ are **isotopic** if the induced embeddings $$\tilde{\varphi}_0, \tilde{\varphi}_1: V^k \times D^{n-k} \hookrightarrow M^n$$ are isotopic as embeddings.

Comment: Any chance you know how to find the integer number associated to a framing?

Comment: I thought that all tubular neighborhoods of $V^k$ in $M^n$ are isotopic (Hirsch, Theorem 5.3). Why wouldn't all $\tilde{\varphi}_0, \tilde{\varphi}_1$ be automatically isotopic as well?

Comment: I realize the difference here. There're two choices being done. First of a diffeomorphism $\Phi: N(V^k)\to \nu(V^k)\subset M^n$ from the abstract normal bundle of $V^k$ to a neighborhood (so called tubular neighborhood) of $V^k$ in $M^n$. The second is a choice of framing, so say frame $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_{n-k}:V^k\to N(V^k)$. Now the embedding $V^k\times D^{n-k}\to M^n$ induced from this choice of framing is $(p, x^1,...,x^{n-k})\mapsto \Phi(x^1\sigma_1(p)+...+x^{n-k}\sigma_{n-k}(p))$. 

Thm 5.3 in Hirsch just says the choice of $\Phi$ is unique up to isotopy. The choice of framing is not.